# Partition-Generated Recurrence Relation

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, terminology

Suppose you have a series $\{A_n\}$ with the following recurrence relation:
$$A_{n+1} = \sum_{\lambda(n)}\prod_{i=1}^{|\lambda|}A_{\lambda_i}$$
where $\lambda(n)$ is an integer partition of $n$ and $|\lambda|$ is the number of elements $\lambda_i$ of the partition.

Is there a word for this recurrence relation? Any key words I could search for related to it?

Edit- I originally thought this sequence would count unlabeled rooted trees of size $n$, but neglected to consider that as written this would count trees with multiple branches of the same size more than once, provided that size was greater than two. The proper recurrence relation for that case would be $$A_{n+1} = \sum_{\lambda(n)}\prod_{k\in\lambda}{A_k-1\choose deg(k)}\frac{1}{A_k-deg(k)}$$ where $deg(k)$ is the number of times $k$ appears in $\lambda$.

Comment: Wow, big mistake. Swapped out a sum for a product, should be what I meant now.

Comment: With an offset of $1$, the simple recurrence at the top is [OEIS A093637](https://oeis.org/A093637). (That is, your $A_8$ is their $a_7$.) That sequence is also the number of unlabelled rooted trees on $n$ vertices such that the sizes of the subtrees of each non-leaf vertex are weakly increasing from left to right. There doesn’t seem to be much information — in particular, there are no references.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you, that does seem correct. For future reference, how did you find this out? Is it possible to search OEIS for a particular recurrence relation? Or did you just generate some numbers and search for the resultant sequence?

Comment: I generated $1,1,2,4,9,20,49$ and searched; that was enough to narrow it down to two possibilities (if it was in OEIS at all), and one of them was the desired sequence. When you had the incorrect version up, I searched on `unlabeled rooted trees` to save myself the effort of checking by hand.